# Changing value of a integer entry in a Immutable Record

Tags: reactjs, flux, immutable.js

How do I update the value of a entry `valueb` in Immutable Record in my Flux Store every time a particular action take place? I have my Record Code like this:-

```
const myRecord = Immutable.Record({
    valuea: false,
    valueb: 0
});
```

Now in my Action I have this code in my Store :-

```
case ActionTypes.someAction:
        if(some_condition) {
            state = state.merge({
                'valuea': true,
            });
        }
        state = state.update({
            'valueb' : myRecord.get('uploadedFiles')+1,
        });
        return state;
```

The problem is that `valueb` is not being updated. This code shows me value a final value 0 being logged in the console from the view listening to this store.

Comment: what do you get if you log `state` before the `return state;`? Can you show the code where you log out valueb

Comment: @wgcrouch I get an error. Basically what is happening is when I add the `state.update` code with my `state.merge`, I get a error in the corresponding failure action i.e `case ActionTypes.someActionFailure` . Removing the `state.update` portion logs no error.

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` and then some more lines :) . The corresponding failure action is basically an error of the API Call I am making via Axios. But my Success Action is successful which I can see from the `200 Ok` being logged in the Network Console.

Comment: Any idea what is wrong here @wgcrouch

Comment: well that error message seems to relate to some other code, so I would start there

Comment: @wgcrouch Is the syntax okay? I mean according to the docs this should work right?

Comment: it looks ok, I would use `state = state.set('valuea', true)` instead as you are only changing a single value